# Why do you put a question on hold after OP shows an effort to improve it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, off-topic, suggested-edits

I asked a question 12 hours ago.
[Do more "animal sacrifices, desecrations of cemeteries" happen at Halloween?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23657/is-halloween-dangerous-for-young-people)

When I checked it back there was 2 close-votes and explanations about why it would be closed.

I listened to the advices and I updated the question to clarify it and to ask about a more specific claim. I also asked in the comments section if I can improve the question any better.

Then it was put on hold by a moderator.

So, Why would a question put on hold after OP shows an effort to improve it? Why not give a suggestion and wait for a while first? I'm already willing to update the question to make it better. There are a lot of people on this platform that asks a question and disappears.

Other than that, Can I still word this question in a way that it can be on-topic? (if you still think it is off-topic). Any suggestions?

Note: I wasn't looking for a religious answer. There might be police investigations about the rituals.

Note 2: Updated the question based on suggestions. Please consider re-opening.

Comment: I am not quite sure what kind of answer you would expect. The question is about religious beliefs of religious people. Maybe ask on [Christianity.SE]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question needs work before it's answerable. That's why it's on hold.

As skeptics, the only thing we can say about supernatural claims is that they are not scientific, nor that they have any proof.

The problem is that the Church positions *assumes* these things to be true. We *assume* these things to be false, because they are unproven.

We can salvage your question by sticking to verifiable facts:

- Is Halloween a satanic ritual? *off topic*
- Is a satanic ritual evil? *off topic*
- Does a satanic ritual endanger children? *off topic, unless a specific, scientifically addressable claim of harm is made*
- Do more "animal sacrifices, desacrations of cemeteries" happen at Halloween? *this is on topic*

If you edit your question to be solely about facts, we can reopen it. As it stands, it's not appropriate here.

Comment: I asked for suggestions for wording before also. How about "Are Halloween rituals dangerous/harmful for young people and is there any police investigation about this?". Is this on-topic?

Comment: No, @ermanen. I've given you an example in my answer. Use that.

Comment: Is it ok to make it a more generic title like: "Do more satanic rituals happen at Halloween?" or "Do more rituals happen in Halloween?". Then the details are in the question.

Comment: We can't address that, because there is no such thing as an official list of what actions constitute a satanic ritual, since it's pretty much a novelty thing.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will follow your suggestion. I'm sometimes having a hard time to understand what is on-topic. But I'm learning :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's off-topic, because the 'danger' in the claim results from the Catholic belief that it's "dangerous" to be open to associating with "the devil".

I.e. part of the claim is that the devil is dangerous (other parts of the claim are that some Halloween celebrations are devil-oriented and/or open people to devilish influence).

IMO the question "is the devil dangerous?" is perhaps off-topic on Skeptics.

The "danger to young people" which is in the claim is, I presume, the dangers which come from the devil (e.g. temptations, obsessions, compulsions).

The claim doesn't even say that this happens to many youngsters. Assuming that there are a hundred million children, is your question asking for proof that no devilish harm comes to any of them?

Also note that questions about 'motive' are off-topic at Skeptics: so "did the devil make him do it?" would be off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Showing that you, as the OP, are open to improving the question is great - but it doesn't automatically make the question on-topic.

What I'm saying is, that just because you're improving the question, it doesn't mean it wont still be put on hold while you're doing so. Often this is done to stop you getting a whole load of down votes

Comment: Or, bad answers.